# Problema al pasar el dato que tengo en un input type="hidden"a un array de javascript

Tags: javascript, mvc, razor

Al hacer click en el `botón` agregar carrito (llamo a una función de `javascript` que me agregaría el idLibro que esta en el `input type="hidden"` al `array` de la función de `javascript`) después pasaría ese array de `javascript` al `controlador`para hacer algo (pero eso seria otro tema).
el `input` lo tengo así:

```html
<input type="hidden" name="inputText" id="inputText" value="@item.IdLibro" />
```

El problema que tengo es que cuando hago click en el botón agregar a carrito en cualquier fila de mi tabla, siempre me agrega el mismo idLibro a el `array`de `javascript`. Por ejemplo:
tengo una `tabla` con 5 filas, en c/u de las filas tengo el `botón` agregar carrito y los datos del registro. Entonces  si en la fila 1 hago click en agregar a carrito, en el `array` me guarda el idLibro 25, pero si hago click en agregar a carrito en la fila 4 también me vuelve a cargar el idLibro 25.

Aca el `.cshtml`

```html
@model List<Librery_MVC.Models.Libro>

<p id="pText">hola</p>

<div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table table-striped table-primary mt-5 table-bordered" id="myTable">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th></th>
                <th>Id</th>
                <th>Nombre</th>
                <th>Autor</th>
                <th>Categoria</th>
                <th>Descripcion</th>
                <th>Precio</th>
                <th>Imagen</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>

            @if (Model.Count() == 0)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="6" style="color:red">
                        No Match any document
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }

            else
            {
                foreach (Libro item in Model)
                {

                    autor = sa.getAutor(item.IdAutor);
                    editorial = es.GetEditorial(item.IdEditorial);
                    category = cs.getCategoria(item.IdCategoria);

                <tr>
                    <th>
                        <input type="hidden" name="inputText" id="inputText" value="@item.IdLibro" />
                        @Html.ActionLink("Mostrar", "MostrarLibro", "Usser", new { idLibro = item.IdLibro }, new { @class = "btn btn-info" })
                        <button onclick="pushData();" class="btn btn-info">Agregar a carrito</button>
                    </th>
                    <th>@item.IdLibro</th>
                    <th class="col-md-2">@item.Nombre</th>
                    <th>@autor.Nombre</th>
                    <th>@category.Nombre</th>
                    <th class="col-md-3"><textarea rows="4" cols="40" readonly>@item.Descripcion</textarea></th>
                    <th>@item.Precio</th>
                    <th><img src="/@item.UrlImagen.Replace("\\", "/")" width="80" height="100" /></th>
                </tr>
                }
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Y aca la función de `javascript`

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
    //creo el array
    var myArr = [];

    function pushData() {
        //obtengo valores del input hidden "inputText"
        var inputText = document.getElementById('inputText').value;
        //añado los elementos al array
        myArr.push(inputText);

        var pval = "";

        for (i = 0; i < myArr.length; i++) {
            pval = pval + myArr[i] + "<br/>";
        }

        //muestro el array
        document.getElementById('pText').innerHTML = pval;
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

estás creando el hidden dentro de un bucle, luego lo que está ocurriendo es que se están creando varios hidden todos con el mismo id (inputText). Cuando haces

```
var inputText = document.getElementById('inputText').value;
```

Te devuelve el primer elemento que encuentra con ése id, independientemente del botón que hayas pulsado.

Podrías modificar tu función pushData para que reciba directamente el idLibro, algo así:

```
<button onclick="pushData('@item.IdLibro');" class="btn btn-info">Agregar a carrito</button>
```

y el script así:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    //creo el array
    var myArr = [];

    function pushData(idLibro) {

        myArr.push(idLibro);

        var pval = "";

        for (i = 0; i < myArr.length; i++) {
            pval = pval + myArr[i] + "<br/>";
        }

        //muestro el array
        document.getElementById('pText').innerHTML = pval;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Gracias @S. Bonet! funciona perfecto!